# ZF2 fileupload not required with annotationbuilder

Tags: validation, file-upload, upload, zend-framework2

I'm stuck at a problem with ZendFramework 2, annotationbuilder and fileupload.
for at contact form i want user the choice to upload a file.

I got everything to work except the file upload, if there is no file a get the 
error:
File was not uploaded

I'm using annotationbuilder to create the form. some annotations is cut out with a space for testing. but did not help.

the Annotation class:

```
<?php
/**
 * @Annotation\Name("message")
 * @Annotation\Hydrator("Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ObjectProperty")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="contact_message")
 */
class Message {



    /**
     * @Annotation\Exclude()
     * 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var integer 
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Select")
     * @Annotation\Flags({"priority": 600})
     * @Annotation\Required({"required":"true" })
     * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StringTrim"})
     * @ Annotation\Validator({"name":"StringLength"})
     * @Annotation\Options({"label":"About:"})
     * @Annotation\Attributes({"options":{"1":"PlaceHolder","2":"Test"}})
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var String
     */
    private $about;

    /**
     * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Text")
     * @Annotation\Flags({"priority": 500})
     * @Annotation\Required({"required":"true" })
     * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
     * @ Annotation\Validator({"name":"EmailAddress"})
     * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Name:"})
     * @Annotation\Attributes({"required": true,"placeholder": "Your name ... "})
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var String
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Text")
     * @Annotation\Flags({"priority": 500})
     * @Annotation\Required({"required":"true" })
     * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
     * @ Annotation\Validator({"name":"EmailAddress"})
     * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Subject:"})
     * @Annotation\Attributes({"required": true,"placeholder": "Subject ... "})
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var String
     */
    private $subject;

    /**
     * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\File")
     * @Annotation\Flags({"priority": 500})
     * @ Annotation\Required({"required":false })
     * @ Annotation\Filter({"name":"StringTrim","filerenameupload":{"target": "./img","randomize":true}})
     * @ Annotation\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
     * @ Annotation\Validator({"name":"StringLength"})
     * @Annotation\Options({"label":"File:"})
     * @Annotation\Attributes({"required": false})
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var String
     */
    private $file;

    /**
     * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Textarea")
     * @Annotation\Flags({"priority": 500})
     * @ Annotation\Required({"required":"true" })
     * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
     * @ Annotation\Validator({"name":"EmailAddress"})
     * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Message:"})
     * @Annotation\Attributes({"required": true,"placeholder": "Message ... "})
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var String
     */
    private $message;

    /**
     * WARNING USING THESE IS NOT SAFE. there is no checking on the data and you need to know what
     * you are doing when using these.
     * But it a great function for lazy people ;)
     * 
     * @param ANY $value
     * @param ANY $key
     * @return $value
     */
    public function __set($value,$key){
        return $this->$key = $value;
    }    

    /**
     * WARNING USING THESE IS NOT SAFE. there is no checking on the data and you need to know what
     * you are doing when using these.
     * But it a great function for lazy people ;)
     * 
     * @param ANY $value
     * @param ANY $key
     * @return $value
     */
    public function __get($key){
        return $this->$key;
    }    

    /**
     * WARNING USING THESE IS NOT SAFE. there is no checking on the data and you need to know what
     * you are doing when using these.
     * This is used to exchange data from form and more when need to store data in the database.
     * and again ist made lazy, by using foreach without data checks
     * 
     * @param ANY $value
     * @param ANY $key
     * @return $value
     */
    public function populate($array){
        foreach ($array as $key => $var){
            $this->$key = $var;
        }
    }


    /**
    * Get an array copy of object
    *
    * @return array
    */
    public function getArrayCopy()
    {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }


}
?>
```

and the add Action in my controller:

```
<?php

use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Form\Annotation\AnnotationBuilder;
use Contact\Entity\Contact;
use Contact\Entity\Company;
use Contact\Entity\Message;
use Contact\Controller\EntityUsingController;

class MessageController extends EntityUsingController {


    public function addAction(){

        $message =  new Message();

        $builder = new AnnotationBuilder();
        $form   =  $builder->createForm($message);
        $form->bind($message);

        $request = $this->getRequest();

        if ($request->isPost()) {

            $form->bind($message);
            $requestData = array_merge_recursive((array) $request->getPost(),(array) $request->getFiles());
            $form->setData($requestData);
            var_dump($request->getFiles());
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getEntityManager();

                $em->persist($message);
                $em->flush();                

                $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('Contact Saved');

                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('contact');
            }
        }

        return new ViewModel(array(
            'form' => $form
        ));
    }

    private function storeFile($file){

        if (!$this->getConfiguration('fileupload')){
            return null;
        }

        $fileBank = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('FileRepository');
        $entity = $fileBank->save('/tmp/myfile.jpg');
    }
}
?>
```

I hope anyone can help my get around this problem.

Comment: are you sure that everything is ok with the upload location?

Comment: Also in your addAction, you never call storeFile($file), or I'm i missing something?

Comment: Sorry, the storage is not build yet, i'm trying to get it to accept that i did not choose any file to upload

Comment: so you want the form to return valid when no file is choosen?

Comment: Yes exactly :), but it ain't for some reason

Comment: if you remove required true?

Comment: thats my problem, in the annotation i have tried both removing the required and setting it to false and nothing helps

Comment: remove the validator as well?

Comment: yes just did and nothing changed, but when i completely removes the annotation it works. If i remove the file input after the formCreate($message) it still doesnt validate.

Comment: so if you remove annotations and keep it working like that?

Comment: Yes by removing the annotation completely it works, I think I'll make a work around by adding the file after creating the form from annotation builder, and then do a check afterwards. Maybe even make a service event to make it even more extensible, but it just sounds like a long trip around the annotation "bug"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the annotation builder.
I found a lot of places on the net that confirmed that i should be correct.
so i ended up hacking it by adding the file input after the form was build.

```
if ($this->getConfiguration('fileupload')){
    $companyForm->add(array( 
        'name' => 'file', 
        'priority' => 300,
        'type' => 'file',
        'options' => array( 
            'label' => 'File:', 
        ), 
    ),array('priority' => 300));
}
```

checks if the configuration allows for file upload. an extra feature I put in now that I could not set the file upload as an annotation

Answer (score 0):

If you're still interested in another way:

You can try the AllowEmpty annotation:

```
* @Annotation\AllowEmpty(true)
```

Or you can try to disable the validator for that field in the controller:

```
$form->getInputFilter()->remove('file');
```

Comment: sounds good I'll try working with that, as of now I'm using the remove filter, but I'm more interested in AllowEmpty